# Inconsistency in emacs' rules of scope?

Tags: lexical-scoping, setq, dynamic-scoping

I have always felt that emacs' rules of scope are a bit strange
and prone to contradictions.  In fact I have even attempted to file
bug reports just to be told that my interpretation of the rules of scope
was wrong,  which I always reluctantly accepted.

This time I think I nailed a contradiction caused by such rules.  In the
emacs manual page for `setq` (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Using-setq.html), it is
stated that `setq` is **exactly** the same as using `set` followed by a
quote, but the following two examples show that it isn't:

```
(progn
  (setq a "one")       ;; Global variable
  (let ((a "two"))     ;; Local variable
    (set 'a "three")   ;; Using "set + quote" affected the GLOBAL variable "a"
    a))                ;; Return local variable a

=> "two"               ;; The local variable "a" remained with its let-value "two" and was not affected by "set + quote"
```

Here is the second example:

```
(progn
  (setq a "one")       ;; Global variable
  (let ((a "two"))     ;; Local variable
    (setq a "three")   ;; Using "setq" affected the LOCAL variable "a"
    a))                ;; Return local variable a

=> "three"             ;; The local variable "a" was changed by setq
```

My question is thus:  Am I once more misinterpreting the rules of scope
or have I really found an inconsistency in these rules?

Perhaps I should add that the above code was run with lexical binding enabled. Otherwise I believe there is no inconsistency

---

My emacs version is: GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2021-03-26

Comment: Perhaps I should add that the above code was run with lexical binding enabled.  Otherwise I believe there is no inconsistency.

Comment: You should add that bit of information to your question, not add it as a comment.

Comment: Done.   Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lexical scope (recently added to emacs) changes the rules, and some documentation is still out of date. The current documentation for setq is [this manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Variables.html) which says

> When dynamic variable binding is in effect (the default), set has the
> same effect as setq, apart from the fact that set evaluates its symbol
> argument whereas setq does not. But when a variable is lexically
> bound, set affects its dynamic value, whereas setq affects its current
> (lexical) value.

It looks like the page you are viewing was written for an earlier version of emacs and hasn't been updated; you might want to file a documentation bug.

Comment: FWIW, both `lexical-binding` and the manual excerpt you quote were released almost a decade, and three major releases, ago.

Comment: Wow, how time flies!